# Netbeans has phantom html error

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Using Netbeans 8.0.2, I'm getting an error (red circle/exclamation mark) on the tab for the html file, but there is no error shown in the html itself:

[image: Phantom HTML error]

While just an irritant, it does keep drawing my eye to it.  I'd like to make it either go away or show exactly where the error is, but I can't find anything online about this particular problem.

Comment: Do not post a screenshot of your code, [edit] your question and post the code itself. So far, this question is off-topic. What have you done to find the error yourself? Have you validated your code? Have you removed parts from your code until the error notification goes away?

Comment: The solution I'm looking for doesn't involve the code, it involves how Netbeans is displaying the error (or non-error, as the case may be).  Did you even read what I wrote?

Comment: Is the error notification appearing on _any_ tab with _any_ code?

Comment: It only happens on some (not all) HTML files, never on .java files.  And to answer your question, yes, I did validate the code and got "Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show." from https://validator.w3.org/.  That's the FIRST thing I did.

Comment: @BobStout You could try restarting netbeans. I have a laptop as my secondary PC and I sometimes carry around my projects on a USB stick. This USB stick is pretty slow and has caused some weirdness in the past similar to this, even on java projects. Maybe it could be related to slow storage?

Comment: @SydLambert:  I've done that, and rebooted also.  It just keeps coming back.  The files are on the local hard drive, also. But that's an avenue to explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two more things to try:

- check Action Items window to see if there is something (Window->Action Items)
- could be issue of NetBeans - check IDE log if there is some exception via View->IDE log

Comment: I didn't find anything in Action Items, but found 2 instances of this in IDE Log:  WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil]: FileUtil.normalizeFile(C:\SVN\MealOrder\web\WEB-INF) took 522 ms. Result is C:\SVN\MealOrder\web\WEB-INF.  However have the same warning in another project and it's not doing the phantom error thing there.  :/

Comment: There are harmless. Have you copied something to the file? Is it possible that you've copied some non-printable characters? Also did you make sure that Action Items are actually showing data (there are 3 buttons on left side of the window to select where Action Items should look for data - file, project, all projects - make sure you have setting that matches your setup). You can also delete NetBeans cache (location is in Help->About and remove the cache directory and restart NetBeans)

Comment: Deleting the cache cleared it up.  I'd like to know what causes it so I can prevent it in the future, but I'll gladly accept this as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually just add a space in the file and then save it. It is annoying but it does the job.

Comment: Nope, still gives me the error symbol in the tab.  :/